# ubuntu 18.04: Xserver has problems with Matrox GA

Tags: drivers, 18.04, xorg

The machine is an IBM xeon server with matrox graphics: MGA G200EV / G550 AGP.
The system worked fine with xenial (16.04).

Now I migrated from 16.04 to 18.04, but the `xserver` has problems, it cannot load module `mga` (does not exist), nevertheless the kernel loaded `mgadriver` modules. Thus I have only access to a console.

I tried yet to install `xserver-xorg-video-*`, but without success.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: is this a proprietary driver? after I upgraded I had to re-add the ppa for graphix drivers and upgrade: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa